# A certain kind of set of integers

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let us call a set $S$ of integers *sparse* if for any four integers $a,b,c,d \in S$ such that $a<b<c<d$, we have that $a+d \ne b+c$. Define $P(n)$ to be maximal size of a sparse subset of $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$. Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(n)/n=0$?

Comment: If the sparse sets have to be built iteratively, then the the $n^\text{th}$ distinct sparse set is the set of the first $n$ Fibonacci numbers, so it is at least true in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's true. It follows from (the finitary version of) [Szemerédi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem): if a set $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ has positive upper density, then for every positive integer $k$ it contains an arithmetic progression of length $k;$ see [Endre Szemerédi, On sets of integers containing no $k$ elements in arithmetic progression, *Acta Arithmetica* **27** (1975), 199–245](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa27/aa27132.pdf).  The case $k=4$ was proved earlier: Endre Szemerédi, On sets of integers containing no four elements in arithmetic progression, *Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar.* **20** (1969), 89–104. (Of course, a "sparse" set contains no arithmetic progression of length $4.$)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an explicit, tighter bound for the size of a sparse set.  If $A\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is sparse, then every pair of distinct elements of $A$ has a distinct sum.  There are $\Theta(|A|^2)$ pairs of distinct elements, but only $O(n)$ different sums that they can have.  By the pigeonhole principle we conclude that $|A|$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$, and hence $|A|/n$ is $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Good, but since we're being explicit, why not just say $|A|\lt2\sqrt n$?